# How to replace existing values by new values from look-up list without causing NA?

Tags: r, lookup

I have a data frame. One column contains the following values:

```
df$current_column=(A,B,C,D,E)
```

A vector contains a look up value:

```
v <- c(A=X, B=Y)
```

I want to replace this column to come up with a list of (X, Y, C,D,E)

I am thinking to create a new column like

```
df$new_column <- v[df$current_column]
```

It does the replacement of A and B but it also makes C,D,E as NA (X,Y, NA, NA, NA).

How to keep C,D and E or is there any other way?

Comment: There is no `N/A` in R.

Comment: Should be NA. Corrected. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

looks like ifelse() could help:

```
d$current_column <- ifelse( d$current_column == A, X, 
                    ifelse( d$current_column == B, Y, d$current_column ))
```

Comment: It may work  but it is not generic enough. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

We can create a logical index with `%in%` and then do the conversion

```
i1 <- df$current_column %in% names(v)
df$new_column <- df$current_column
df$new_column[i1] <- v[df$new_column[i1]]
df$new_column
#[1] "X" "Y" "C" "D" "E"
```

---

Or use a single `ifelse`

```
 with(df, ifelse(current_column %in% names(v), 
                   v[current_column], current_column))
```

#### Update

If the 'current_column' is `factor` class, convert to `character` class and it should work.

```
 df$new_column <- as.character(df$current_column)
 df$new_column[i1] <- v[df$new_column[i1]]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(current_column = LETTERS[1:5], 
                              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
v <- setNames(c('X', 'Y'), LETTERS[1:2])
```

Comment: It does not work though:
current_column <-c("A","B","C","D","E")
another_column <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
df <- data.frame(current_column, another_column)
v <- c("A"="X", "B"="Y")

i1 <-df$current_column %in% names(v)
df$new_column <- df$current_column
df$new_column[i1] <- v[df$new_column[i1]]
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i1, value = c(NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 5L)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: @user2029709  It does work based on the example I posted.

Comment: @user2029709 Use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in creating the dataset.  Otherwise, the column will be a `factor` class and with `ifelse`, it gets the `numeric` encoding.  With `df <- data.frame(current_column, another_column, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` , it works.

Comment: @user2029709  If you point the cursor towards the votes, it will show.

Answer (score 0):

user2029709,

-- was working off of your little example; for a more generic approach it would be nice to see a snippet of the real data or close simulation.  In any case, here is something that may work for you better, without coding manually all `ifelse()` options, and is still a relatively straightforward solution:

```
vd <- data.frame(current_column = names(v), new_column = v, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- merge(df, vd, by = 'current_column', all.x = TRUE)
df$new_column <- ifelse(is.na(df$new_column), df$current_column, df$current_column)
```

You may have to modify data types when creating vd `data.frame` to assure proper merge.

Best, 
oleg